# Check if values satisfy conditions of Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have the django model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    some_number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, blank=False)
    optional_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And I'm trying to validate whether a list of data will satisfy the conditions of the model. Say I have this list:

```
myData = [
        ['bob', 25.22, None], #should pass
        ['jane', 123.45678, "foo"], #should fail some_number max_digits=6
        [None, 25.22, "bar"] #should fail name blank=False
    ]
```

Is there a clean and fast way to test if each row will pass or fail and also get which condition is not met if it fails?

Comment: Keep in mind that "edit" means that anybody can fix the question. When only the OP can fix it, then edit is wrong. Then you probably want to close vote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `full_clean()` method on a model instance

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

myData = [
        {"name":'bob',"some_number": 25.22,"optional_field": None},
        {"name":"jane","some_number": 123.45678,"optional_field": "foo"},
        {"name":None, "some_number":25.22, "optional_field": "bar"}
    ]

for row in myData:
    try:
        instance = LCSData(**row)
        instance.full_clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e.message_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could make [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) based on the Data model and than provide the data to that form. The form will validate given data and output any errors (with descriptions) if necessary. If you don't want to save the given data to the database just override ModelForm save() method so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'm concerned about the overhead of bringing the ModelForm class into it because I may potentially be validating ~1 million rows. I suspect it's possible to do something like `try: <make model instance> catch DataError as e: <do something with e> `